# what algorithm does cv::arclength use to compute perimeter?

Tags: opencv

I am currently doing a project which requires me use some structural analysis like finding the perimeter and area. I have successfully obtained the contour of the object. 
when I  use contour.size() function it return 1108(in this case)
when I used cv::arclength(contour) function it returns 1200.

shouldn't the Perimeter be the number of points of the contour.(the contour is the external boundary of the object)? Which should I trust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not necessarily, with `cv::arclength` you summarize the euclidean distances between the consecutive points in the curve.

Here is a code snippet of `cv::arclength`:

```
...
const Point2f* ptf = curve.ptr<Point2f>();
...
for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    Point2f p = ptf[i];

    float dx = p.x - prev.x, dy = p.y - prev.y;
    buf[j] = dx*dx + dy*dy;

    if( ++j == N || i == count-1 )
    {
        Mat bufmat(1, j, CV_32F, buf);
        sqrt(bufmat, bufmat);
        for( ; j > 0; j-- )
            perimeter += buf[j-1];
    }

    prev = p;
}

return perimeter;
```

Comment: so this can be trusted instead of just finding the size of the contour right ?

Comment: It depends on the usage. Your discrete curve can be considered as the approximation of a continuous one and in this case `cv::arclength` is a better approximation of the length. Or say you have two points `(0, 0)` and `(10, 0)`, what's the length of the curve (in this case line) 2 or 10? :)